# automaticlly send E-mails when a new entry is created on strapi

Tags: strapi

Let's say I have a content type named Order with the following fields:

| Name | Product | E-mail |
| --- | --- | --- |

and the public has permission to post new entries for this type.

How can I send an email confirming the order when ever a new post request ( new entry ) is made by the public ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using webhooks on `entry.create` event, integrating it with some worker or email API.

On this example, we can see a cloudflare worker for email sending:

https://dev.to/gzuidhof/sending-e-mails-from-cloudflare-workers-2abl

Here the Strapi documentation about how to deal with webhooks:

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/webhooks.html#entry-create